# how to resize an ImageView Programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to resize an ImageView when I touch on it. It will be perfect to resize it like when you do the zoom in google maps or in a mobile browser but if just touching it I can resize it will be enough. Is that possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just catch the event of touching this ImageView and than just adjust height & weight :

```
touched_image_view.getLayoutParams().height += 20;
touched_image_view.getLayoutParams().width += 20;
```

Or you can just create and set new LayoutParams :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
touched_image_view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: TO implement this with the pinch to zoom gesture, look into ScaleGestureDetector.  It will return a scale factor that you'll want to multiply the width and height by instead of adding.