# how to increase/decrease imageView width and height with buttons in android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have two buttons in my android app.
"(+)Increase image dimension" & "" (-)Dicrease image dimension""
and i want on click to increase or dicrease a imageView that i have.

that's all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283773/how-to-resize-an-imageview-programmatically

Comment: Always add code to your questions to help us pin point your problem and offer solutions

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to increase `width` and `height` with 5 :

```
final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();

    buttonIncrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutParams.width += 5;
            layoutParams.height += 5;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

imageView.getLayoutParams().height += 1; (or -)
imageView.getLayoutParams().width  += 1;

Comment: Please edit formatting. Copy and paste is not an answer :)