# Images on a Image

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I am new on this community and i have no idea what I have to search for. So I hope there is no thread like this.

I want to create a java Android App in Android Studio where I can open a floor plan(image) and insert icons(images). If i click once on the icon it should be movable and the size of the icons should be adjustable with a seekbar.

I googled for these functions and the only thing I found was that:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
Can someone tell me which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal ImageViews https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html
with events (OnClick, OnTouch).
If you want to resize view, check this answer 
-https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283837/8180966

For rotation

```
//@param rotation The degrees of rotation.
imageView.setRotation(float rotation);
```

If you want your icons to look nice at any size, you should look at Vector Graphics (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

Hope, this will help :)

Comment: What happens with the icons when I zoom in the floor plan? Stay the icons at the floor plan position or the display position?

Comment: Depends on your layouts and how you'll implement this idea

Answer (score 0):

You may please visit the following page (especially layer list section of the page) of android developer site.  There are a few things which you may be interested in and which may serve either as a solution or an alternative to your problem.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html